# v-text-field oninput handler for max quantity only handles it once

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a v-text-field with an input handler that prevents entering too high of a value. E.g. max quantity is 50, so my handler will set the quantity to 50 if user enters 98 or if they enter a non numeric value. However the handler will only do so once. After that, the value technically remains 50, but the field will show the user's input.

It doesn't seem to be an issue if I use the native html , anyone know how to deal with this in Vuetify? I've added a link to the sandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v-text-field-issue-w43sx?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the number input? That's exactly what it's for...

Comment: Prototyping an app currently and just wanted to use Vuetify for default styles and slots.

Comment: In that case, just add `type="number"` to your Vuetify input

Answer (score 0):

You should use **@change** instead of **@input**. Input fires once you starts typing. Change will be watching for any changes.
And in check parseInt. Vuetify automatically renders model text as a string. In start 0 will be "0".

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="quantity"
    label="Quantity"
    @change="preventOverflow"
  />

preventOverflow() {
  if (parseInt(this.quantity) > 20) {
    this.quantity = 20;
  }
},
```